# Time and Date picker (Javascript/PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm desperately in need of a way to implement a day and time picker using either PHP or Javascript or both.

The first HTML Select Input will have Today and Tomorrow (with Today selected as default on page load).
The second HTML Select Input will have time listed with interval of 30mins.
The time displayed should be relative to the current time i.e if current time is 15:00 then don't display anything before that e.g 14:00.
If user selects tomorrow, then all the times should be shown.

This is my code so far:

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select class="form-control" id="" name="" required>
        <option value="0" selected>ASAP</option>
        <?php
        for($hours=$new_time; $hours<23; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
            for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) // the interval for mins is '30'
                echo '<option 
             value='.$hours.$mins.'>'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'
                .str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

My code loops through time from 10:00 to 23:00 and lists them as options.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Example = https://deliveroo.co.uk/

Comment: The Time is already there so for Date use jQuery datepicker and you can also do one more thing `loops through time from 10:00 to 23:00` put server time to GMT and get the current time and can also utilize it like shop is closed or time left to open (By the way these days every 2nd person is trying to start online food business in UK) it's crazy may be at day end they just placing order for each other and no real consumer left to place order online :)

Comment: You are using bootstrap framework so can use bootstrap date and time picker too,

Comment: Hello Shehary, funny comment. I'm not using bootstrap.
Basically I can loop through time and display the time I want, I can also display today & tomorrow on the first drop down list. My 1st question is how can one drop down affect the contents of the other dropdown dynamically? My 2nd question is how can I loop through time and only show time that is future of current time. I'm good with PHP but not javascript.

Comment: So how do you explain your markup ? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#selects

Comment: @moh.ABK may be it's funny but it's true, I myself design and develop couple of online food ordering site (For UK clients) but now I'm fedup but anyhow if you need any help or suggestion just ping me here, things will be more hectic when dealing with cart and products and sub products and side offers and deals and daily offers and special offers and drinks and if you have custom food ordering then the phase will come where you might start pulling your hair if you will not be on right track from start

Comment: How can I contact you?

Comment: @moh.ABK you have today and tomorrow in `days` drop down, how many days you need in drop down like if today is 4th sep so how many more days you wana show in drop down?

Comment: I'm not using multiple days. I'm just using Today and Tomorrow.
For Today show time from current time to 2300 with 45mins interval.
For Tomorrow show time from 1000 - 2300 with 45mins interval.
Also they should be dependent on each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just kept the previous answer cause other people might just need that loop. In this answer I have added quick Javascript function to switch today and tomorrow. I think this might help you.

```
<label>Day</label><br>
<select  onchange="changeTime(this);">
  <option value="today">Today</option>
  <option value="tomorrow">Tomorrow</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label>Time</label>
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select class="form-control today" id="" name="" required>
        <option value="0" selected>ASAP</option>
        <?php
        $initial = strtotime(date('H', time()) . ':00:00');
        for (; $initial < strtotime("23:59:59");  $initial = strtotime("+30 minutes", $initial)) {
          echo '<option value='. date('H:i', $initial) .'>'. date('H:i', $initial).'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select class="form-control tomorrow" id="" name="" required style="display:none;">
        <option value="0" selected>ASAP</option>
        <?php
        $initial = strtotime('12:00:00');
        for (; $initial < strtotime("23:59:59");  $initial = strtotime("+30 minutes", $initial)) {
          echo '<option value='. date('H:i', $initial) .'>'. date('H:i', $initial).'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeTime (obj)
   {
     if(obj.value == 'today') {
        document.getElementsByClassName('today')[0].style.display='block';
        document.getElementsByClassName('tomorrow')[0].style.display='none';
     }
     else{
      document.getElementsByClassName('tomorrow')[0].style.display='block';
      document.getElementsByClassName('today')[0].style.display='none';
     }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider looking into [Moment JS](http://momentjs.com/), a Javscript library built for manipulating date/time data.  If you're able to use it, your solution could be as simple as:

```js
//Store the select control element
var selectControl = document.getElementById('thisNeedsAnIdToBeJsSelectable');

//Loop through every half hour
for(var timeIncrement = moment().startOf('hour'), i = 1 /*Put this as 1 because ASAP already takes option 0*/; timeIncrement.isBefore(moment().endOf('day')); i++){
  timeIncrement.add(30, 'minutes')
  var newOption = document.createElement('option');
  newOption.value = i;
  newOption.innerHTML = timeIncrement.format("h:mm a"); //This is a Moment.js time-format value
  selectControl.appendChild(newOption);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select class="form-control" id="thisNeedsAnIdToBeJsSelectable" name="" required>
    <option value="0" selected>ASAP</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Basically, the loop starts by asking Moment to instantiate a variable, 'timeIncrement' at the beginning of the hour.  The condition for our loop is to make sure that timeIncrement is still before the end of the day, and after each loop it increments i - a variable we made to give each option a sequential 'value' attribute.  Then each iteration does the following:

- It adds thirty minutes to our timeIncrement variable.
- It creates and new option with i as the value, and the formatted string version of our timeIncrement variable as the display string.
- It adds that option to the selector.

Comment: This is really good PawnStar, I'll work on this.
Little help, how to I make the time take consideration of current time eg if its 15:00 then just show time from 15:15 to 23:00

Comment: Yeah, it's currently running in a way that makes it only show increments after the beginning of the current hour, but you could fix that really easily by putting an if statement inside the loop, something like "if(timeIncrement.isBefore(moment())) continue;"

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you tried is good. Instead of adding external Javascript library you can try following code to get it work.

**For today**

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select class="form-control" id="" name="" required>
        <option value="0" selected>ASAP</option>
        <?php
        $initial = strtotime(date('H', time()) . ':00:00');
        for (; $initial < strtotime("23:59:59");  $initial = strtotime("+30 minutes", $initial)) {
          echo '<option value='. date('H:i', $initial) .'>'. date('H:i', $initial).'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

**And for tomorrow**

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select class="form-control" id="" name="" required>
        <option value="0" selected>ASAP</option>
        <?php
        $initial = strtotime('12:00:00');
        for (; $initial < strtotime("23:59:59");  $initial = strtotime("+30 minutes", $initial)) {
          echo '<option value='. date('H:i', $initial) .'>'. date('H:i', $initial).'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is excellent Beroza. But I guess I need javascript to show either the today code or tomorrow code based on selection of a dropdown. Any ideas?